# Flash media Server, Live Video Mic Echo when using a Apple Cinema Display

Tags: flash, audio, video, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I'm using Flash Media Server to create a 1:1 video chat. The problem I'm having is that when I use my apple cinema display I get horrible Echoing, even with the reduce echo box checked. If I don't use my cinema everything works fine with the built in macbook mic.

Any idea what's going on and how I can fix this?

I have to believe there is a setting as I can use iChat, Adobe Connect, WebEx, Skype all with my apple cinema and not have this MIC echoing issue.

Thank you

**OUR CURRENT SETTINGS:**

**AUDIO**

```
var options:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
     options.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
     options.echoPath = 256;
     options.nonLinearProcessing = true;
     //options.autoGain = false;

     microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
     microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
     microphone.framesPerPacket = 1;
     microphone.setSilenceLevel(0, 2000);
     microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
     microphone.encodeQuality = 3;        // decrease quality slightly from default (6) to conserve bandwidth 
     microphone.gain = 85;
```

**VIDEO**

```
camera = Camera.getCamera();
     // 2k bytes (or ~16kbps) of bandwidth
     //camera.setQuality( 16384 / 4, 0 );
     camera.setMode(320, 240, 12, false);
     camera.setQuality(18432, 0);
     camera.setLoopback(false); // show local cam before encoding, not after
     camera.setKeyFrameInterval(48); // keyframe interval is at maximum so that we transmit less data
var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
     h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_1_2);
     ns.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;
```

Comment: Hi All, really hoping to hear some advice on this topic. I added our current settings to the Q. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

It's because default flash microphone has no echo suppression. You need to tune it programmatically.
According to reference you need to use [setUseEchoSuppression()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#setUseEchoSuppression%28%29)
You can change some params using enhancedOptions
For examples you can read [Jozsef Vass great article](http://macromedia.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html)

It is not a Mac problem, such behavior appears on PC with Windows and Linux too.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't solving it for us yet. Sadly! ... I updated the question with our settings. ANy suggestions or red flags you're seeing? Right now video quality is nice but there is a lag, and audio is horrible, delayed and choppy, and garbled.

Comment: Also added audio and video settings. Both are now there. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The echoing is still there since you haven't assigned the "**MicrophoneEnhancedOptions**" to your microphone device.

Add this code to your existing specified lines.

**`microphone.enhancedOptions = options;`**

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending MP3, try using AIFF audio format: [Discussion on Apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7937244#7937244)

Or maybe upgrade the firmware, if you haven't: [MacRumors post.](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/12/16/apple-addresses-cinema-display-audio-issues-with-firmware-update/)